# Riesz Theorem on C[K], K compact

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory

I'm studying Riez Theorem on Kreyszig's book: "Introductory functional analysis" , it states that

"Let $l$ a bounded and linear functional on $C[a,b]$ (continuous functions on [a,b]) , then $l$ can be represented as a Rieman-Stieltjes integral
$$l(f)=\int_a^bf(x)d\mu(x)$$
where $\mu$ is of bounded variation on $[a,b]$"

The prove is very clear there, my question is, can I extend this prove to $C(K)$ where K is any compact in $\mathbb R$?.

I know the general Riez-Markov theorem for any Compact Hausdorff Space, but the proof of this is very complicate and this result is bigger than I need. Thank you, any help would be appreciate.

Comment: Maybe it is easier if $K$ is only assumed to be a compact *metric* space, but I doubt that there are "simple" proofs out there for your (already quite) general case.

Comment: That's what I think, Riesz-Markov uses Borel Measures, that's where I think it's the difficulty, The Riesz on $C[a,b]$  theorem uses just Riemman-Stieltjes measures, I Rather work with those.

Comment: This ought to be possible, generally speaking.  The first question will be, precisely what does it mean to take the Riemann-Stieltjes integral of a function over a set which is not an interval?  The definitions I've seen are pretty closely tied to working on an interval.

Comment: But the idea should be as follows: 
Given a compact $K \subset \mathbb{R}$, choose a closed interval $[a,b]$ containing $K$.  Define a functional $l'$ on $C([a,b])$ by $l'(g) = l(g|_K)$.  By the Riesz theorem for intervals, there is a function $\mu' : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$, with bounded variation, such that for every $g \in C([a,b])$ we have $l'(g) = l(g|_K) = \int_{[a,b]} g(x)\,d\mu'(x)$.  Now let $\mu = \mu'|_K$ be the restriction of $\mu'$ to $K$, which still has bounded variation.  Try to show that $l(f) = \int_K f(x)\,d\mu(x)$ for all $f \in C(K)$.

Comment: Somewhat relevant to the comment of @FriedrichPhilipp, one can use a similar idea to see that in order to show the Riesz(-Markov) theorem for arbitrary compact metric spaces, it is sufficient just to prove it for the Hilbert cube $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$, in which any other compact metric space can be embedded.

Comment: Yes @NateEldredge, I got the idea, but, is it possible define such integral over a compact? I mean we can't take partitions lightly.

Comment: @TomBuilder: Right, that's the issue.  I don't know exactly what the right definition would be.  I think most people just switch over to Lebesgue integrals (with respect to Borel measures) at this stage of the game.

Comment: Yes, that is why everyone works with Borel Measures, thank you anyway!

Comment: One note that might be useful, though: any continuous $f : K \to \mathbb{R}$ has a (typically non-unique) continuous extension $g : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ (Tietze extension theorem).  You could then show that for any such extension we have $l(f) = \int_{[a,b]} g(x)\,d\mu'(x)$, and in particular the right side describes a well-defined functional of $f$, independent of the extension chosen.  So that at least gives some sort of integral representation for the functional $l$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $[a,b]$ be the smallest containing interval for the compact set $K$. Then $K\setminus[a,b]$ is an open subet of $\mathbb{R}$ and, as such, consists of an empty, finite, or countably infinite set of disjoint open intervals $\{ I_j \}$. So every function $f\in C(K)$ can be extended linearly on each $I_j$ in order to obtain a unique $\tilde{f} \in C[a,b]$ such that $\|\tilde{f}\|_{C[a,b]}=\|f\|_{C(K)}$. It seems to me this extension operator is linear. That is, if $E(f)=\tilde{f}$, then $E : C(K)\mapsto C[a,b]$ is linear. And $E$ is isometric because the sup norm is never increased by such an extension, and it's certainly not smaller than the sup norm for the original $f$.

Every continuous linear functional $\Phi$ on $C(K)$ is a continuous linear functional on $E(C(K))\subset C[a,b]$ and extends continuously to its closure $\overline{E(C(X))}$ in $C[a,b]$. Then, by the Hahn-Banach Theorem, $\Phi$ extends to a continuous linear functional $\tilde{\Phi}$ on $C[a,b]$. Finally,
$$
           \Phi(f)= \tilde{\Phi}(Ef) = \int_{a}^{b}\tilde{f}(t)d\rho(t).
$$
I'm stuck at this point because I cannot see how to argue that $\rho$ is constant on the open intervals $\{I_j\}$, even though I suspect there must be some way to arrange for this to hold by requiring certain properties for the extension, if it isn't generally true.